# Where do I go to upload pictures in version magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, image-upload

Anyone if you can help.

I can't find out where to  upload my pics anymore in Magento 1.7.0.2.

I don't know much about it, only a tiny bit.

I have no developer to help me. I used to be able to upload but now I can't find the button not sure where to go. Tried inserting a picture here of my screen but not able to.

Anyone know what it even looks like the button? I am in pages in the backend trying to edit it in the wysiwyg part.

I clicked on icon of tree to upload picture but I can't I can only insert pics not what I want.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6qkqrNEg1M - this video might help you

Comment: Do you mean an image in a CMS page, a product image, a logo, a placeholder image, etc.? Please specify.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 methods to upload images:

> Via FTP

via FTP (like filezilla for example) and upload your images inside the `media` folder.

> Via Image Upload on CMS Page / Static Block

You can upload images inside the editor at cms pages oder static blocks.
Open `cms` > `cms pages` and choose or create a page. Inside the wysiwyg Editor you can click on `Show/Hide Editor` and at the image button. Here is the part you search for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow Steps listed below:

1. Click on "Show / Hide Editor".
2. Click on "Insert Image..." button.